# How to use callback function under document ready function

Tags: javascript, function

I have used this function for form validation. I have used this function without

```
$ function(document).ready(function(){.............});
```

Its working well. Now I want to add my code under this

```
$ function(document).ready(function(){.............});
```

How could I do that. Thanks.

```
function myFunction () {
        var a = document.getElementById("num").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var msg = "";

        if(a==""){
            msg+="Please Fill this field.\n";
            num.className = "color";
        }

        if(b==""){
            msg+="Please Fill this field.\n";
            num2.className = "color";
        }
        if(msg=="") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Please fill the user name";
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML="Please Put your E-mail";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(myFunction)` should work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ myFunction(); });
```